# Jenkins unable to generate test report due to NoClassDefFoundError - ParseResultCallable

Tags: junit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I set up a Jenkins job to run some integration tests. After testing finishes, Jenkins should look for test report in settings. However, it gives following error:

```
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/tasks/junit/JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:90)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:120)
at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:137)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:74)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1779)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my Publish Junit result setting:
[image]

I checked the path for those xml files in workspace, they do exist. I'm not sure what could be wrong. My JUnit Plugin version is 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a version mismatch between the JUnit version in your build and the version that is loaded into Jenkins. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24946 may provide some insight, but in general, you need to be very careful that the versions are compatible.

Comment: I had the same problem, JUnit plugin updated to 1.6 and broke everything.  Downgraded it back to 1.1 and all worked fine again.

Comment: My issue was resolved when I uninstalling `JSUnit plugin v1.6` & `JUnit Attachments Plugin v1.5` not sure which one caused issue. (my Unit Plug version is 1.24)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some configuration issue, somewhere in configuration it's not updating with latest version.
At some point of time you have to work with latest version.
Instead of downgrading just create a new branch of your project. 
I created new branch of my project then build went smoothly although still it is failing with older branch. So better you work with latest version of JUNIt by creating new branch, jenkin will pick it automatically.

2. Also Wiping out Current Workspace may help
   [image]